# Formally proving $p\wedge q \rightarrow p$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I want to write a full prove for $p\wedge q \rightarrow p$ without using deduction, using only ${\neg, \rightarrow}$ connectives.

I want to use the standard axiomatic system:

$\alpha\rightarrow(\beta\rightarrow\alpha)$

$(\alpha\rightarrow(\beta\rightarrow\gamma))\rightarrow((\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\gamma))$

$(\neg\beta\rightarrow\neg\alpha)\rightarrow((\neg\beta\rightarrow\alpha)\rightarrow \beta)$

I only succeeded to prove it using deduction. I tried to work back from deduction to full proof using the general fact (on which deduction theorem proof relies) that $\alpha \vdash\beta \Rightarrow \vdash\alpha\rightarrow B_i$, for every $B_i\in\{B_i\}_1^n$ the prove sequence of $\beta$ from $\alpha$ , in order to find a formula $\gamma$ to apply $A2$ such that $(\neg(p\rightarrow\neg q)\rightarrow(\gamma \rightarrow p))\rightarrow((\neg(p\rightarrow\neg q)\rightarrow\gamma)\rightarrow(\neg(p\rightarrow\neg q)\rightarrow p))$

My proof using deduction:

First $p\wedge q \rightarrow p \equiv \neg(p\rightarrow\neg q)\rightarrow p$

1. deduction: $\neg(p\rightarrow q)\vdash p$
2. applying lemma: $\alpha\vdash\beta\Leftrightarrow\neg\beta\vdash\neg\alpha$ one may prove: $\neg p\vdash p\rightarrow q$
3. deduction: $\neg p,p\vdash q$
4. A3:
   $(\neg q\rightarrow\neg p)\rightarrow((\neg q\rightarrow\ p)\rightarrow q)$
5. A1 : $\neg p\rightarrow (\neg q\rightarrow\neg p)$
6. MP by assumption $(\neg q\rightarrow\neg p)$
7. A1 : $p\rightarrow (\neg q\rightarrow p)$
8. MP by assumption $(\neg q\rightarrow p)$
9. MP 6 from 4:$(\neg q\rightarrow\ p)\rightarrow q$
10. MP 8 from 9:$q$

Comment: Are you allowed to use the deduction theorem?

Comment: @Bram28 sorry, but I want a full proof (avoiding deduction theorem)

Comment: You're missing something very big here. The deduction theorem is a completely constructive theorem; it tells you precisely how to transform a proof for $S+A ⊢ B$ to a proof for $S ⊢ A→B$. So just keep applying that transformation to the proof you already have and you would be done.

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Work backwards. Since you need to show $\vdash \neg (p \rightarrow \neg q) \rightarrow p$ you probably want to show $\neg (p \rightarrow \neg q) \vdash p$ and then use the Deduction theorem.

Second, since the goal is now $p$, you probably want to use axiom 3 and show $\neg p \rightarrow \varphi$ and $\neg p \rightarrow \neg \varphi$ for some $\varphi$.

What might be that $\varphi$? Well, you have as a premise $\neg (p \rightarrow \neg q)$, so that could be your $\neg \varphi$, so then the $\varphi$ would be $p \rightarrow \neg q$.

OK, so here's the basic proof strategy/plan:

1. Show that $\vdash \neg p \rightarrow (p \rightarrow \neg q)$ (which is easy: prove $p, \neg p \vdash q$ and then apply Deduction theorem twice)
2. Show that $\neg (p \rightarrow \neg q) \vdash \neg p \rightarrow \neg (p \rightarrow \neg q)$ (even easier, using axiom 1)
3. Given 1 and 2, and using axiom 3, we can quickly get: $\neg (p \rightarrow \neg q) \vdash p$
4. Apply Deduction theorem on 3 to get $\vdash \neg (p \rightarrow \neg q) \rightarrow p$, i.e. $\vdash (p \land q) \rightarrow p$

Comment: "Apply Deduction theorem on 3 to get ⊢¬(p→¬q)→p, i.e. ⊢(p∧q)→p"  That won't work for this question.  The Deduction Theorem just consists of a statement.  Dan needs to apply a suitable *proof* of The Deduction Theorem.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood good point ... just asked the OP if the use of the Ded Thm is allowed.

Comment: @Bram28 thanks for your answer but as I mentioned in the previous comment, I want to avoid deduction.

Answer (score 1):

I use Polish notation.  This means that (x$\rightarrow$y) gets translated Cxy and $\lnot$x gets translated to Nx.  $\lnot$(p$\rightarrow$$\lnot$q) translates to NCpNq.

> 1 CpCqp axiom
>
> 2 CCpCqrCCpqCpr axiom
>
> 3 CCNpNqCCNpqp axiom
>
> 4 CCN Nq N p CCN Nq p Nq 3
>
> 5 C CCNNqNpCCNNqpNq C NCpNq CCNNqNpCCNNqpNq 1
>
> 6 CNCpNqCCNNqNpCCNNqpNq {5, 4}
>
> 7 C CCNNqNpCCNNqpNq C Np CCNNqNpCCNNqpNq 1
>
> 8 C CCCNNqNpCCNNqpNqCNpCCNNqNpCCNNqpNq C NCpNq CCCNNqNpCCNNqpNqCNpCCNNqNpCCNNqpNq 1
>
> 9 CNCpNqCCCNNqNpCCNNqpNqCNpCCNNqNpCCNNqpNq {8, 7}
>
> 10 CC NCpNq C CCNNqNpCCNNqpNq CNpCCNNqNpCCNNqpNq CC NCpNq CCNNqNpCCNNqpNq C NCpNq CNpCCNNqNpCCNNqpNq 2
>
> 11 CCNCpNqCCNNqNpCCNNqpNqCNCpNqCNpCCNNqNpCCNNqpNq {10, 9}
>
> 12 CNCpNqCNpCCNNqNpCCNNqpNq {11, 6}
>
> 13 CC Np C CNNqNp CCNNqpNq CC Np CNNqNp C Np CCNNqpNq 2
>
> 14 C CCNpCCNNqNpCCNNqpNqCCNpCNNqNpCNpCCNNqpNq C NCpNq CCNpCCNNqNpCCNNqpNqCCNpCNNqNpCNpCCNNqpNq 1
>
> 15 C NCpNq CCNpCCNNqNpCCNNqpNqCCNpCNNqNpCNpCCNNqpNq {14, 13}
>
> 16 CC NCpNq C CNpCCNNqNpCCNNqpNq CCNpCNNqNpCNpCCNNqpNq CC NCpNq CNpCCNNqNpCCNNqpNq C NCpNq CCNpCNNqNpCNpCCNNqpNq 2
>
> 17 CCNCpNqCNpCCNNqNpCCNqpNqCNCpNqCCNpCNNqNpCNpCCNNqpNq {16, 15}
>
> 18 CNCpNqCCNpCNNqNpCNpCCNNqpNq {17, 12}
>
> 19 C Np C NNq Np 1
>
> 20 C CNpCNNqNp C NCpNq CNpCNNqNp 1
>
> 21 CNCpNqCNpCNNqNp {20, 19}
>
> 22 CC NCpNq C CNpCNNqNp CNpCCNNqpNq CC NCpNq CNpCNNqNp C NCpNq CNpCCNNqpNq 2
>
> 23 CCNCpNqCNpCNNqNpCNCpNqCNpCCNNqpNq {22, 18}
>
> 24 CNCpNqCNpCCNNqpNq {23, 21}
>
> 25 C CCNNqpNq Cp CCNNqpNq 1
>
> 26 C CCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq C NCpNq CCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq 1
>
> 27 CNCpNqCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq {26, 25}
>
> 28 C CCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq C Np CCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq 1
>
> 29 C CCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNqCNpCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq C NCpNq CCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNqCNpCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq 1
>
> 30 CNCpNqCCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNqCNpCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq {29, 28}
>
> 31 CC NCpNq C CCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq CNpCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq CC NCpNq CCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq C NCpNq CNpCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq 2
>
> 32 CCNCpNqCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNqCNCpNqCNpCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq {31, 30}
>
> 33 CNCpNqCNpCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq {32, 27}
>
> 34 CC Np C CCNNqpNq CpCCNNqpNq CC Np CCNNqpNq C Np CpCCNNqpNq 2
>
> 35 C CCNpCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNqCCNpCCNNqpNqCNpCpCCNNqpNq C NCpNq CCNpCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNqCCNpCCNNqpNqCNpCpCCNNqpNq 1
>
> 36 CNCpNqCCNpCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNqCCNpCCNNqpNqCNpCpCCNNqpNq {35, 34}
>
> 37 CC NCpNq C CNpCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq CCNpCCNNqpNqCNpCpCCNNqpNq CC NCpNq CNpCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNq C NCpNq CCNpCCNNqpNqCNpCpCCNNqpNq 2
>
> 38 CCNCpNqCNpCCCNNqpNqCpCCNNqpNqCNCpNqCCNpCCNNqpNqCNpCpCCNNqpNq {37, 36}
>
> 39 CNCpNqCCNpCCNNqpNqCNpCpCCNNqpNq {38, 33}
>
> 40 CC NCpNq C CNpCCNNqpNq CNpCpCCNNqpNq CC NCpNq CNpCCNNqpNq C NCpNq CNpCpCCNNqpNq 2
>
> 41 CCNCpNqCNpCCNNqpNqCNCpNqCNpCpCCNNqpNq {40, 39}
>
> 42  CNCpNqCNpCpCCNNqpNq {41, 24}
>
> 43 CC p C CNNqp Nq CC p CNNqp C p Nq 2
>
> 44 C CCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq C NCpNq CCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq 1
>
> 45 CNCpNqCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq {44, 43}
>
> 46 C CCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq C Np CCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq 1
>
> 47 C CCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNqCNpCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq C NCpNq CCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNqCNpCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq 1
>
> 48 CNCpNqCCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNqCNpCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq {47, 46}
>
> 49 CC NCpNq C CCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq CNpCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq CC NCpNq CCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq C NCpNq CNpCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq 2
>
> 50 CCNCpNqCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNqCNCpNqCNpCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq {49, 48}
>
> 51 CNCpNqCNpCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq {50, 45}
>
> 52 CC Np C CpCCNNqpNq CCpCNNqpCpNq CC Np CpCCNNqpNq C Np CCpCNNqpCpNq 2
>
> 53 C CCNpCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNqCCNpCpCCNNqpNqCNpCCpCNNqpCpNq C NCpNq CCNpCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNqCCNpCpCCNNqpNqCNpCCpCNNqpCpNq 1
>
> 54 CNCpNqCCNpCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNqCCNpCpCCNNqpNqCNpCCpCNNqpCpNq {53, 52}
>
> 55 CC NCpNq C CNpCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq CCNpCpCCNNqpNqCNpCCpCNNqpCpNq CC NCpNq CNpCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNq C NCpNq CCNpCpCCNNqpNqCNpCCpCNNqpCpNq 2
>
> 56 CCNCpNqCNpCCpCCNNqpNqCCpCNNqpCpNqCNCpNqCCNpCpCCNNqpNqCNpCCpCNNqpCpNq {55, 54}
>
> 57 CNCpNqCCNpCpCCNNqpNqCNpCCpCNNqpCpNq {56, 51}
>
> 58 CC NCpNq C CNpCpCCNNqpNq CNpCCpCNNqpCpNq CC NCpNq CNpCpCCNNqpNq C NCpNq CNpCCpCNNqpCpNq 2
>
> 59 CCNCpNqCNpCpCCNNqpNqCNCpNqCNpCCpCNNqpCpNq {58, 57}
>
> 60 CNCpNqCNpCCpCNNqpCpNq {59, 42}
>
> 61 CC Np C CpCNNqp CpNq CC Np CpCNNqp C Np CpNq 2
>
> 62 C CCNpCCpCNNqpCpNqCCNpCpCNNqpCNpCpNq C NCpNq CCNpCCpCNNqpCpNqCCNpCpCNNqpCNpCpNq 1
>
> 63 CNCpNqCCNpCCpCNNqpCpNqCCNpCpCNNqpCNpCpNq {62, 61}
>
> 64 CC NCpNq C CNpCCpCNNqpCpNq CCNpCpCNNqpCNpCpNq CC NCpNq CNpCCpCNNqpCpNq C NCpNq CCNpCpCNNqpCNpCpNq 2
>
> 65 CCNCpNqCNpCCpCNNqpCpNqCNCpNqCCNpCpCNNqpCNpCpNq {64, 63}
>
> 66 CNCpNqCCNpCpCNNqpCNpCpNq {65, 60}
>
> 67 CC NCpNq C CNpCpCNNqp CNpCpNq CC NCpNq CNpCpCNNqp C NCpNq CNpCpNq
>
> 68 CCNCpNqCNpCpCNNqpCNCpNqCNpCpNq {67, 66}
>
> 69 CpCNNqp 1
>
> 70 C CpCNNqp C Np CpCNNqp 1
>
> 71 CNpCpCNNqp {70, 69}
>
> 72 C CNpCpCNNqp C NCpNq CNpCpCNNqp 1
>
> 73 CNCpNqCNpCpCNNqp {72, 71}
>
> 74 CNCpNqCNpCpNq {68, 73}
>
> 75 CCNpNCpNqCCNpCpNqp 3
>
> 76 C CCNpNCpNqCCNpCpNqp C NCpNq CCNpNCpNqCCNpCpNqp 1
>
> 77 CNCpNqCCNpNCpNqCCNpCpNqp {76, 75}
>
> 78 CC NCpNq C CNpNCpNq CCNpCpNqp CC NCpNq CNpNCpNq C NCpNq CCNpCpNqp 2
>
> 79 CCNCpNqCNpNCpNqCNCpNqCCNpCpNqp {78, 77}
>
> 80 C NCpNq C Np NCpNq 1
>
> 81 CNCpNqCCNpCpNqp {80, 79}
>
> 82 CC NCpNq C CNpCpNq p CC NCpNq CNpCpNq C NCpNq p 2
>
> 83 CCNCpNqCNpCpNqCNCpNqp {82, 81}
>
> 84 CNCpNqp {83, 74}